# Node.js: require() and MODULE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: node.js, require

As a learning exercise, I am attempting to build a router in Node.js, which is meant to be reusable.

The file structure for my router looks like this:

```
/myProject
    app.js
    /routes
        index.js
        about.js
    /modules
        /router
            router.js
```

In `app.js`, I create a `router` object, and pass it the path to my routes folder:

```
var Router = require('./modules/router/router');
var router = new Router('./routes');
```

Within the constructor of the router object, I load filenames into an array from the path passed to the object, and attempt to add them to an object as a module:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var routes = {}
var routesFolder;

function Router(routesPath){
    this.routesFolder = routesPath;
    fs.readdir(this.routesFolder, this.loadRoutes);
}

Router.prototype.loadRoutes(err, files){
    for (var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
        var c = files[i].split('.');
        if(c[1] === 'js'){
            try{
                var t = require(routesFolder + '/' + c[0]);
                routes['/' + c[0]] = t[c[0]];
            }
            catch(err){
                console.log('Error parsing file: ' + files[i];
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `index.js` and `about.js` files look like this:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    // Some code here
}
```

I run `node app.js`, and I pass the router object `./routes` as the `route`'s path. The file names load just fine, but my console output is:

```
Error parsing: index.js
{ [Error: Cannot find module './routes/index'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
Error parsing: about.js
{ [Error: Cannot find module './routes/about'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

I have attempted to alter my routes files in a few different ways:

```
module.exports = function(){...}
module.exports.index = function(){...}
```

But this has no effect. From what I understand about `node` and `require`, this should work. I'm a bit of a novice, so please forgive me if the issue here is something silly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use an absolute path to your `routes` folder:

```
var path = require("path");
var Router = require('./modules/router/router');
var router = new Router(path.join(__dirname,'routes'));
```

I think what is happening is that `fs.readdir` is using the `process.cwd` which is the directory of `app.js` but `require()` always uses the location of the current script when resolving relative paths and is thus looking for files like `/myProject/modules/router/routes/index.js`.

Comment: That fixed it! I had guessed that the issue was something to do with the path referencing, but I had been assuming that both fs and require handled references the same way.